# Is it possible to display symbols between facets with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put symbols between my facets in ggplot, to visualize the relation between different facets, e.g.:

```
□ + □ - □ = □
```

with every square being a facet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add grobs to the gtable as post-processing,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(data.frame(f=1:2)) + facet_wrap(~f) 

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
pan <- g$layout[grepl("panel", g$layout$name),]
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, unit(2,"line"), pos = min(pan$l)+1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, textGrob("+", gp=gpar(cex=2)), l = min(pan$l)+2, t=unique(pan$t))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]